# Multiple Complexities

Tags: time-complexity

If I have a algorithm where a part of it has complexity big-O(nlogn) and part of it has complexity big-O(n). What would the final complexity of the algorithm be? As far as I am aware, it would be big-O(nlogn).

Comment: what's your algorithm? please don't hide critical things from us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, the worst case possible is what counts,
in your case o(nlog(n)).

Comment: I had a follow-up question on this if you don't mind? I have an algorithm which has running complexity O(nlogn) and one which has O(n^2). I ran them both with samples of 1 up to 5000 and plotted the time taken for each sample. What I found odd is that as the sample size increased, the one with O(n^2) became quicker than the O(nlogn) one. Can this happen or are the chances I work out the time complexity wrong?

Comment: No, i dont think it is possible, you can compare the graphs of the functions to see for yourself, the horizontal axis will be the inputs that you check and the vertical will be the runtime of the currespondimg input.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "part of it" ...

Let's assume you have a for loop that has a complexity of O(n) and a binary search for O(logn)

If you program look like this:

```
for(int i=0; i < n; i++) { // O(n)
 /// some stuff here
}
binarySearch(); // O(logn)
```

Time Complexity would be O(n)

---

However if have this situation:

```
for(int i=0; i < n; i++){ // O(n)
   binarySearch(); // O(n * logn)
}
```

Time Complexity would be O(nlogn)

**Edit:**

If the algorithm is composed of different blocks with different time complexities, then algorithm time complexity = max(O(block1), O(block2), ...)

Comment: I actually have a very similar situation, a for loop of complexity O(n) and a sort of O(nlogn). But the sort happens independent of the loop.